# How to remove duplicated values from attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with duplicated values in single cell, please tell me how can i remove duplicated values using sql or pl/sql only.

```
 | Test
-+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 999999999(10145) 999999999(10145) 999999999(10145) 999999999(10145)
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 113307425(2) 310122174(2) 310122174(2) 113307425(2)
```

Comment: Please add sample data as text and explain what the expected output is with an example

Comment: i attached an image to show my issue

Comment: _As text_, not as an image of text

Comment: @Pioter Please do **NOT** post images of code or data. Post it as text so that people can copy/paste it (or even better, post it as DDL/DML statements that can be copy/pasted and run).

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira No, its an Oracle question not SQL Server and it does not appear to be about deleting duplicate rows but removing repeated terms in a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with a back-reference to match the repeating terms:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT '9999999(12345) 9999999(12345) 9999999(12345) 9999999(12345)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '([^ ]+)( \1)+', '\1' ) AS replaced_value
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | :------------- |
> | 9999999(12345) |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1766f9e7bc3ee2adbaa52e04bf2a0b26)*

---

**Updated**: For new data in the 6th edit:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT '9999999(12345) 9999999(12345) 9999999(12345) 9999999(12345)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '113307425(2) 310122174(2) 310122174(2) 113307425(2)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to find the terms in the string and then use `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates and the `LISTAGG` to concatenate them back into a single string.

```sql
WITH bounds ( id, value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT ROWID,
         value,
         1,
         INSTR( value, ' ', 1 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( value, ' ', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
),
strings ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         id,
         CASE end_pos
           WHEN 0
           THEN SUBSTR( value, start_pos )
           ELSE SUBSTR( value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT LISTAGG( value, ' ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY value ) AS unique_values
FROM   strings
GROUP BY id
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | UNIQUE_VALUES             |
> | :------------------------ |
> | 9999999(12345)            |
> | 113307425(2) 310122174(2) |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fec9ace5d4e51164f8c6406c8306d422)*

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Oracle allows for recursive subquery factoring that can be harnessed to apply regexp based substitutions repeatedly:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT '9999999(12345) 9999999(12345) 9999999(12345) 9999999(12345)' FROM DUAL;

WITH rep(n,s,n_maxrep) AS (
    SELECT 1
         , value
         , 1 + LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '[^ ]', ''))
      FROM test_data
 UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1
         , REGEXP_REPLACE ( s, '([^ ]+)(( [^ ]+)*)( \1)+', '\1\2' ) 
         , n_maxrep
      FROM rep
     WHERE n <= n_maxrep
)
SELECT s FROM rep WHERE n = n_maxrep;
```

**Explanation**

The query repeatedly applies the same basic regex-based replacement of a single verb duplicate. to the original column. A 'verb' in this context is the maximal sequence of consecutive non-space chars. The duplicates may be next to each other or be separated by other verbs.

The maximum possible number of such replacements is known beforehand: `n-1` for `n` verbs, when all verbs are identical. This is equivalent to the number of occurrences of the separating character in the original value.

Everything else is syntactic sugar. Oracle builds the nested chain of subqueries on its own.

Note that the limit `n_maxrep` is actually 1 + <number_of_separator_occurrences>. This is necessary as the base case ( `n=1` ) does no replacement.